# Oracle SQL update string field with yearweek to date field

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

In my oracle DB I have a string field with values like 1850, where 18 is year and 50 is week.
So I need to update my field from string type to datetime type.

I tried to use

```
SET FIELD = TO_DATE(FIELD, 'YYIW')
```

But it doesn't work and returns me an exception

```
ORA-01820: format code cannot appear in date input format
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean 2018 for "18"? Is it the week number according to ISO8601

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7a3c11811dceadba35ee64107071222c)

```
SET FIELD = TO_CHAR(DATE FIELD, 'IYYYIW')
```

Comment: I think the OP asks for the other way around. Convert a string (or number) to `DATE`